# Kendo UI : Tabstrip content should redirect to another View in the same Tabstrip on button Click

Tags: kendo-tabstrip

I have a Tabstrip and in the content of that Tabstrip , I have a button. So when I click on the button it will redirect to the other page. But is there any way to make it just redirect in the content of the same Tabstrip?

** This question has been asked earlier but nobody answered,Can someone help me please !! Im stuck !!.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default behavior of a Kendo tabstrip link by adding a custom handler to the tab strip's "select" event.

```
$("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
    select: function(event) {
        // Detect if this is a case where override is needed
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // Navigate to the desired content
    }
});
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip