# Kendo UI template syntax in TabStrip

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a kendo template that contains a tabstrip. In this tabstrip I have item that use the kendo template syntax like so:

```
items.Add().Text("Block Attributes").LoadContentFrom("BlockAttributes", "Properties", new { blockRef = "#=BlockRef#" });
```

In this case the block ref gets output as expected. However when using the `.Action()` method like so:

```
items.Add().Action("Details", "Properties", new { fiscalYear = Model.FiscalYear, blockRef = "#=BlockRef#" }).Text("Details");
```

the propertyId uses the literal string that is typed so it will try to navigate using "#=BlockRef#" as a parameter which results in an error.

Why does it work ok for the former but not the latter? How do I get this to work?

Comment: I am not familiar with `.Action()`. What is the intent? Might be able to use `.Content()` with `@Url.Action()`

Comment: @SteveGreene I wish to use the tabstrip item to open a link when clicked instead of displaying content.

Comment: In that case, I would probably handle the [select event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/events/select) and redirect via javascript. Here is a [js example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182430/kendo-ui-tabstrip-content-should-redirect-to-another-view-in-the-same-tabstrip).

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have found, although probably ill-advised is to do the following:

```
items.Add().Text("Details").Url(Url.Action("Detail", "Properties", new { fiscalYear = Model.FiscalYear, blockRef = -1 }).ToString().Replace("-1", "#=BlockRef#"))
```

It seems there is no way to get Kendo templates to work directly with Url.Action(), the html has to first be generated and then parameters have to be individually replaced. I used -1 as BlockRef is expecting an int and there is no possible way for -1 to appear naturally in the system.